# How to download multiple zip files using requests and extracting to a folder using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, zip

I have a url_file.txt file with few links to download the zip files directly. The content of url_file.txt file has 6 urls.So I have to take each url from this file and get the zip file. Then extract it to the destination folder. The destination folder contains all the extracted application extensions. So the code I have written is:

```
        import os, io, zipfile, requests
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        save_path = cwd +"\\test"

        os.chmod(save_path,0o777)
        with open('url_file.txt', 'r') as urll:
          for i,val in enumerate(urll):      
            path = val      
            r = requests.get(path)
            z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
            z.extractall(save_path)
```

But I am getting error while executing this. If I pass a url directly in requests. It is downloading and extracting the application. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Someone please give me some suggestion to resolve this. The error I am getting while executing the above code is:

```
 z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
 File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
 self._RealGetContents()
 File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
 raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
 zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: @MattDMo I was facing an issue in posting. Please check now, I have added the whole question now.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **full text** of any tracebacks or errors you're getting.

Comment: @MattDMo I have added the error I am getting to the question.

Comment: I would take a look at `r.content` and see what it actually is - you may be getting a 403 Forbidden or 404 Not Found HTTP error. Also, when calling `requests.get()`, use the `stream=True` parameter.

Comment: @MattDMo. Yes I printed "r.content". As you said it has 404 not found message in it. The error is :

   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache Server at www.application.com Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n

Comment: But when I do this : r = requests.get ("https:\\www.downloads\application\extension.zip")
  It is extracting the content fine. if I pass as variable, it is giving this 404 error. Still I am not able to figure out why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226537/discussion-between-saffron-and-mattdmo).

Answer (score 0):

I have converted txt files content to array and passed to the requests. Added these two lines and worked perfectly.

```
text_file = open('url_file.txt', 'r') 
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
```